# How to quit all Finder tabs

Tags: macos, finder, tabs, force-quit

I've configured OSX to force all Finder windows to open in tabs - because this really takes care of all the clutter.

The thing is, there's a shortcut to close all Finder windows, CMD+OPTION+W - and this will conveniently exit and quit all Finder windows completely.

But this does not work for a window with multiple tabs. I've searched Stackexchange and Apple Forums high and dry, and I cannot find a solution. I'd be interested in ANY WAY to achieve this, an AppleScript, a keyboard shortcut...EVEN a third-party app.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which version of OSX/MacOS are you using? CMD+OPTION+W closes all Finder windows for me in High Sierra (10.13.3), whether they have multiple tabs or not.

Comment: I'm on High Sierra 10.13.3 (17D102)

Comment: @Lizzan Just an update. I opened multiple windows with multiple tabs each. Using CMD+OPTION+W will close all windows, except for the first one if it has tabs. So every other Window that has tabs closes and quits completely. But the first original one, if it has tabs, the tabs will remain intact and unaffected.

Comment: Weird, it does every window for me. Are you running any plug-ins or extensions for Finder which might interfere?

Comment: @Lizzan Not at all. I'm running BetterTouchTool, Karabiner, and Bartender 3, as well as CornerClick. But nothing that interferes with Finder. Let me create a screen recording.

Comment: @Lizzan https://youtu.be/3lpZllBHGNk - Maybe this is normal behaviour?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the screencast, it does work the same for me. That would be Finder restoring the last open window when you re-activate it. Sadly, I don't know whether that can be disabled at all, or if it can be disabled separately from restoring all open Finder windows on reboot (if you use that).

Comment: @Lizzan Thanks for confirming, at least I know it's normal behaviour :)

Answer (score 1):

`Command + Option + W` will close ALL Tabs on Finder